# Are fanfic identification questions on-topic on SFF?

Tags: discussion, scope, story-identification

I'm wondering whether fanfic identification questions (i.e. story-identification style questions that are about a fan fiction; note that, normally, the question author would know what particular work the fanfic in question is based on) are on-topic on SFF.
It would appear that they would have been a big part of SFF content had they been on-topic (indeed, IIRC, there are many other online communities dedicated to fanfic identification); yet I have never seen any. Is there another SE network site that fits this category better?
I already know that non-story-identification questions about (well-known) fanfic settings are on-topic; in particular, I've seen a few about (Harry Potter and the) Methods of Rationality. I'm talking about fanfic identification (as described above) questions specifically.

For the record, I'm talking about the case where the general work that the fanfic is based on is otherwise on-topic for SSF, such as Star Trek or Harry Potter.
And yes, I'm considering asking a few questions of this kind (completely seriously, there really are a few fanfics I liked but cannot find anymore) if the general opinion is positive enough. Though I might yet not do that if you guys think that such question would have been too common if their on-topicness was established definitively.

Comment: [Yes.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/are-questions-about-fanfics-on-topic)

Comment: Such as [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89470/help-finding-a-hp-fanfic-with-a-ss-hg-pairing-where-hermione-attends-university)?

Comment: We already have a number of questions about HP:Methods of Rationality, a very popular HP fanfic.

Comment: So does that mean it won't be a problem if I post a fanfic identification question on SFF?

Comment: Not at all, January. We've even answered a few of them here that I'm aware of.